# how to pass item from list in state to child component?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a wizard form - the user is creating fields, and I want to display these fields to him , so I have "fields" list in parent state and I want to call a child component (that presents the field ) by passing it an item from "fields" list in parent state in a loop - and I am struggling with it

the passing item is a JSON with the attributes fro the field (name, label & type)

```js
class Wizard extends React. Component{

  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          showCard:false,
          title:'',
          type:'',
          name:'',
          label:'',
          fields:[]
      };
  }
  
  render(){
      const result = Object.keys(this.state.fields).map((field, index) =>{
          return(
              <FieldsViewer
                  key={index} 
                  field={field}

              />
          )
          })
      return(
          <div className="ui segment">
          <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form"> 
              <div className="field">
                  <input 
                      className="ui header"
                      placeholder="Place your form title here"
                      type="text" 
                      value={this.state.title } 
                      onChange={(e)=>this.setState({title:e.target.value})}
                  />

                  <div>

                  <button 
                  style={{marginTop:"50px" }}
                  className="ui button"
                  onClick={this.CreateProperty}>
                      Add Field
                  </button>

                  </div>
                  {

                      this.state.fields.length>0 && {result}
                  }

                  </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      );
  }

}


const FieldsViewer=(props)=>{
    console.log(props);
    return(
        <div>
            {<label>
                {props.field}:
            <label>
            <input
            type={props.type}>
            </input> 
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you know for certain that all of the keys will be there every time, and will be the same? Because you probably don't need to map over the object keys if so.

Comment: every item has a JSON string with a different name, label & type

Comment: `Object.keys` is used for key-value objects or hashes.
You can use `map()` on your array in order to iterate over each field and generate the component from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the map as you have it, you are creating a FieldsViewer for each key, not for each instance of field.

```
const result = this.state.fields.map((field, index) =>{
          return(
              <FieldsViewer
                  key={index} 
                  field={field}

              />
          )
          })
```

Then you are passing the whole field object to FieldsViewer, so they can be accessed as props.field.label props.field.type etc within that component. Or, you may wish to destructure the object before passing it to the child component:

```
const result = this.state.fields.map((field, index) =>{
          return(
              <FieldsViewer
                  key={index} 
                  name={field.name}
                  label={field.label}
                  type={field.type}
              />
          )
          })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, and get an error in the child when console.log the props

Comment: Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {result}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at Wizard.js:67)
    in form (at Wizard.js:66)
    in div (at Wizard.js:65)
    in Wizard (at App.js:17)

Comment: @July That error isn't in the console.log. Give me a second to track it down.

Comment: ok - so just to clarify, the value of the field looks like that: {0:{" label":"1","name":"2","type":"color"},1:{...}...}

Comment: so - I figured it out - by sending the "result" like an array:
this.state.fields.length>0 && [result] - thankyou for your help - you helped a lot by showing me how to implement the map correct

Comment: @July why is it JSON and not a JS object? Your functions are missing, so I can't say why things aren't working the way you intend.

Comment: it is a js object - not a JSON string - my mistake